# Which date system does VBA recognise/default to?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm writing a vba subroutine in excel to store all date values between 2 dates in a single dimension array and then check for each value in a range on another sheet.

My problem is when the code is grabbing the date values (as an integer(or double - whichever one it is actually using)) it is storing a value 1462 greater than the date value on the sheet.

I am using the 1904 date system so I can use negative time values and i'm in Australia so dates are formatted dd/mm/yyyy.

> As an example;
>
> On the sheet:
> 01/01/2019 = 42004
>
> In the code: 01/01/2019 = 43466

I understand the difference is the same as the difference between date values when using 1900 vs. 1904 date systems which leads me to believe perhaps VBA is defaulting the sheet value to be in 1900 and converting the value to 1904 again when the code is run?

This workbook is set up as follows:

> `Sheet1` contains dates from 01/01/2019 to 25/01/2019 in `Range("A1:A25")`.
>
> `Sheet2` contains 01/01/2019 in cell `A1` and 10/01/2019 in cell `A2`and a activeX `commandbutton`.

And the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myStart As Long
Dim myEnd As Long

myStart = Me.Range("A1").Value
myEnd = Me.Range("A2").Value

Dim v As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim myArr As Variant
ReDim myArr(0 To 100)
x = 0

For v = myStart To myEnd
    If v = Empty Then Exit For
    myArr(x) = v
    Debug.Print ("v = " & v)
    Debug.Print ("myArr = " & myArr(x))
    x = x + 1
Next

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Me.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
x = 0
For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A100")
Debug.Print (CDbl(cell))
    If cell = myArr(x) Then
        Me.Cells(lastrow, 3).Value = cell
        Me.Cells(lastrow, 4).Value = Format(cell, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    End If
    x = x + 1
Next
End Sub
```

The output for the `cell` values in columns 3 and 4 are as follows (first 5 rows for demonstration):

```
       C         D             Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")[when displayed as number format] 
1    43466    01/01/2019                42004
2    43467    02/01/2019                42005
3    43468    03/01/2019                42006
4    43469    04/01/2019                42007
5    43470    05/01/2019                42008
```

The dates are written into the cell as a short date format not numeric value.

Using the intimidate window I've noticed `?cdbl(DateValue(now)) = 43496 (31/01/2019)` which is making me wonder which values are correct for the dates using the 1904 date system? Per the values in Sheet1 it should be `42034`.

Is the issue caused by a data type or function I've used, is it as questioned earlier - the sheet is converting them to 1904 when the values are assigned to Sheet2 with VBA, is it a bug with excel or something else?

I found a question with the same problem [here on mrexcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/656051-problem-excel-2010-1900-vs-1904-date-system-vba.html) however the resolution there was change Excel to use the 1900 date system or subtract 1462 from the values in the code which I'm hoping to avoid both of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the date system in VBA is different than the date system in Excel. You can have these 3 date system options:

- Excel date
- Excel date with 1904 property
- VBA date

**This is the difference:**

The dates are converted to numbers. E.g., every date is converted to a number, but the starting number is a bit different.

- In Excel, the **1** is converted to **01.January.1900**;
- In VBA, the **1** is converted to **31.December.1899**;
- In Excel with 1904, the **1** is converted to **02.January.1904**;

---

The 1904 system (or its lack) is set per Workbook. Thus, if you have 2 workbooks in Excel, one with 1904 and one without it, it would recognize them correspondingly. The system is set in:

**File > Options > Advanced > Use 1904 Date System**

[image]

In general, if there is a chance, that someone somehow changes your workbook with the wrong system, consider adding this check at the openning of the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
    If ThisWorkbook.Date1904 Then
        MsgBox "System is 1904, consider some action!"
    End If        
End Sub
```

If you are wondering which system to choose - I can recommend **never** using the 1904.

- [Story for the adding VBA to Excel and the 1904 problem](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/)

Comment: Ah. The VBA starting date is what I was missing! I bet I can find that info in a billion places now you've explained it!

Comment: @SamuelEverson - the difference for the VBA date and the excel date is done on purpose, to make sure they match each other after 28.Feb.1900.

Comment: I was just reading that through the linked story, very interesting.

Comment: Also I'm only using 1904 to calculate negative time values but working out a way to do that while using the 1900 system is another story for abother day.

Comment: @SamuelEverson - the linked story actually showed BG in another light to me, I was quite impressed to see he popped up with that question that fast. For the 1904 - I never use it, because 4 years in a worksheet is actually a huge difference when mistakes/bugs happen. But, if you can control it well, then it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a solution to my example a colleague mentioned if you dim the date values as the `date` datatype the issues with the values going sheet -> vba -> sheet disappears.