# Issue with for/if loop with the date function

Tags: vba

I am trying to get the word "Yes" to record beside cells in which the date is within 30 days of today however I am having trouble with this for / if statement. I cannot seem to get the correct answer using the code.

```
Private Sub Email_Request_Bttn_Click()

Manager_Email_Month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B37").Value
Another_Employee_Email_Month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B33").Value

LastRow_Month = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D7:D1001"), "*")

    For Email_Month_Row = 7 To (LastRow_Month + 6)

        If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Email_Month_Row, 14).Value <= (Date + 30) Then

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Cells((Email_Month_Row - 1), 17).Value = "Yes"

        End If

    Next Email_Month_Row

        MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

the dates that the code runs through are:

[image]

However, "Yes" is only recorded next to the first 2 rows, which is obviously incorrect.

Any Ideas on what is wrong with this code? could be something to do with the format of the date?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this module/process, but just looking at the code, your if statement checks a condition for Email_Month_Row, but then if correct, you change Email_Month_Row-1. Is this simply causing some sort of offset? Then the 17th and 9th would be set to yes which would be correct.

Comment: Is the `sheet1` an error or are you looking across 2 worksheets?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what your 2 inputs are along with your data and expected output. Seeing the inputs and output given the data will prob speed things up as far as getting a answer. The photo you shared has no value add since we don't know the inputs

Comment: I have [previously asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461825/which-date-system-does-vba-recognise-default-to) about date values and VBA which has some good info in the answer - might be worth testing regarding your 2nd question *Could be something to do with the format of the date?*