# Split date/time not working when 12:00:00 AM

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba function to split date/time on my worksheet
but when it find 0:00AM it will stop and I don't know how to fix this

code

```
Function extractDateTime(strTime As Date) As Variant
  Dim arrD, d As String, t As Date
  arrD = Split(strTime, " ")
  d = arrD(0)
  t = CDate(arrD(1) & " " & arrD(2))
  extractDateTime = Array(d, t)
End Function
```

pic when it find date/time at 12:00:00 AM
function not return value arrD(1) and arrD(2)
[image]

cell value

[image]

pic when function normally working
[image]

Comment: As already pointed out below, if dealing with dates/times, using the proper `Date` variable type is the way to go, no questions asked. But if for some reason you absolutely **have** to use a `String` to represent a date, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: It's handy to know, VBA and your worksheet may interpret non-date formatted dates differently ([see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461825/which-date-system-does-vba-recognise-default-to) ), so as already mentioned it's best practice to use the `Date` variable type when working with dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always handle date/time as *Date*, not text, not numbers, no exceptions. So:

```vb
Public Function ExtractDateTime(Value As Date) As Variant

    Dim d   As Date
    Dim t   As Date

    d = DateValue(Value)
    t = TimeValue(Value)

    ExtractDateTime = Array(d, t)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, also I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing the Date for spaces is not a great way to go about it.

Instead, you can use `Format` to just get the pieces you want.

```
Function extractDateTime(dt As Date) As Variant
    Dim d As String, t As String
    d = Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    t = Format(dt, "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
    extractDateTime = Array(d, t)
   
    Debug.Print d
    Debug.Print t

    Debug.Print Format(dt, "mmm dd, yyyy")
    Debug.Print Format(dt, "mmmm")

    Debug.Print WeekdayName(Weekday(dt))

End Function
```

Kinda seems like a waste of a function tho when you can just do this:

```
Result = Array(Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy"), Format(dt, "hh:mm:ss AMPM"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It might take some time to response since I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Maybe also rethink why you need them split apart in an array like that. That is not covered in your example. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Alright, it works!